# In which reprint did these illustrations for ‘Security Check’ by Arthur C. Clarke appear?

Tags: episode-identification

"Security Check" by Arthur C. Clarke is a charming short story. The first printing was in *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, June 1957. I bought my own issue. The problem is there are no illustrations and I remember illustrations:

1. Hans Muller's (the protagonist) workshop/warehouse, possibly a clearstory.
2. The table with space opera paraphernalia: an alien city diorama, a section of a spaceship, and a raygun. The spaceship fuselage was a 2/3 or 3/4 pipe with scale crew. As I recall, there was a mistake visible in that model: a spaceman (the word 'astronaut' hadn't been invented) in his pressure suit, 'floating' on an umbilical, *INSIDE* the hull.
3. A standard 1950s flying saucer on the yard.

They were pen & ink or ink & wash drawing. I have no idea who the artist was.

The story was reprinted circa 1958(?), possibly in a rotogravure Sunday supplement or a pulp magazine like Colliers or Redbook.

I want the second illustration. It is burned into my memory. Where can I find it?

Comment: According to the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56743), Arthur C. Clarke's "Security Check" was first published in [*The Evening News*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evening_News_(London_newspaper)) (London) for [January 13, 1956](http://eveningnews.atwebpages.com/c.htm), and reprinted in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, June 1957.](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61208)

Comment: The online OED has four citations for "astronaut" antedating the 1956 publication of Clarke's "Security Check"; the earliest is from 1928. I guess the word was popularized by the American space program.

Comment: I think it may have been one of the Clarke short stories published in the UK weekly magazine Speed&Power around 1974 ( though isfdb doesn't mention this magazine ). I think all the stories published in it were illustrated.